# How do I run a Python method as a subprocess?

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython, pthreads, subprocess

i need a help with a python project:

Example:

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):    
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(330, 300))
        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def InitUI(self):
        """
        Subprocess
        """
        subprocess.execMethodFromClass( self , 'Connection' , args1 , args2 , ... )

    def Connection( self ):
        self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connection.connect(( '192.0.1.135' , 3345 ))
        while True:
            data = self.connection.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            else:
                print data
```

Show:

```
subprocess.execMethodFromClass( self , 'Connection' , args1 , args2 , ... )
```

Thanks!

Comment: please make more effort to explain your problem!

Comment: you probably want to run `Connection` in a background *thread* (not subprocess) and report results to the main (GUI) thread using `wx.CallAfter()` (see [Long Running Tasks wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the friendly dogcow says, to run a function in a child process, all you have to do is use a [`multiprocessing.Process`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class):

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
p.start()
p.join()
```

Of course you probably want to hang onto `p` and `join` it later in most* real-life use cases. You're obviously not getting any parallelism by spawning a new process just to make your main process sit around and wait.

So, in your case, that's just:

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.Connection, args=(args1, args2))
```

---

But this probably won't work in your case, because you're trying to call a method on the current `self` object.

First, depending on your platform and Python version, `multiprocessing` may have to pass the bound method `self.Connection` to the child by pickling it and sending it over a pipe. This involves pickling the `self` instance as well as the method. So it will only work if `MyFrame` objects are pickleable. And I'm pretty sure that a `wx.Frame` can't be pickled.

And even if you *do* get the `self` object to the child, it will obviously be a *copy*, not a shared instance. So, when the child process's `Connection` method sets `self.connection = …`, that won't affect the original parent process's `self`.

Even worse if you try to call any `wx.Frame` methods. Even if all the Python stuff worked, on most platforms, trying to modify GUI resources like windows from the wrong process will not work.

The only kinds of objects you can actually share are the kinds you can put in [`multiprocessing.Value`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) or [`multiprocessing.sharedctypes`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.sharedctypes).

---

The way around this is to factor out the code you want to childify into a separate, isolated function, that shares as little as possible (ideally nothing, or nothing but a [`Queue` or `Pipe`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes)) with the parent.

For your example, this is easy:

```
class Client(object):
    def connect_and_fetch(self):
        self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connection.connect(( '192.0.1.135' , 3345 ))
        while True:
            data = self.connection.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            else:
                print data

def do_client():
    client = Client()
    connect_and_fetch()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    # ...
    def Connection(self):
        self.child = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_client)
        self.child.start()
    # and now put a self.child.join() somewhere
```

In fact, you don't even need a class at all here, because the only use you have for `self` is to store a variable that could just as easily be a local. But I'm guessing in your real-life program, there's a bit more state than that.

There's an interesting (if a bit outdated) example on the `wxpython` wiki, called [MultiProcessing](http://wiki.wxpython.org/MultiProcessing), which looks like it does most of what you want and more. (It's using a `classmethod` for the child process instead of a standalone function for some reason, and using old-style syntax for it because it's old, but hopefully it's still helpful.)

---

If you're using `wx` for your GUI, you may want to consider using its inter-process mechanisms instead of the native Python ones. While it's more complicated and less pythonic in the general case, when you're trying to integrate a child process and its communications pipe into your main event loop, why not let `wx` take care of it?

The alternative is to create a thread to wait on the child process and/or whatever `Pipe` or `Queue` you give it, and then create and post `wx.Event`s to the main thread.

---

* Most, not all. For example, if `f` temporarily uses up a whole lot of memory, running it in a child process means you release that memory to the OS as quickly as possible. Or, if it calls badly-written third-party/legacy/whatever code that has nasty and poorly-documented global side-effects, you're isolated from those side-effects. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Comment: But he wants to run a method on `self`, not a module-level function. I don't think a novice can figure out how to get from here to there. Especially since, in his case, it won't work even if he does figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You use subprocess to call another application or script to run in a separate process.

```
subprocess.Popen(cmds)
```

If you need to run some long running process, look into threads or the multiprocessing module. Here are some links:

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/08/03/python-concurrency-porting-from-a-queue-to-multiprocessing/
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/